# How to find out what KDE 3 K -> Log out -> Hibernate really does

Tags: kde

I'm using KDE 3.5.11. I can hibernate my laptop using K -> Log out -> Hibernate. I would like to know how to find out what the button does to do the *very* same from the command line. Therefor my question is more like "how to find out programmatically what a button does" instead of "how do I hibernate" (I could lookup the second myself).

Thanks in advance,

Somebody

Answer (score 0):

Browse the source. For KDE 4, it's [kde-workspace/plasma/desktop/applets/kickoff/core/itemhandlers.cpp](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kde-workspace.git&a=blob&f=plasma/desktop/applets/kickoff/core/itemhandlers.cpp).